# Selenium driver - windowhandle messes up

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm using Selenium WebDriver on Firefox version 48.x.x.  For this to work I need to use GeckoDriver/Marionette driver in order to talk to Firefox driver.  In the older versions of Firefox, Selenium driver is able to get the session ID of a browser window using `driver.getWindowHandle()` however in the new(?) Gecko/Marionette driver, this function returns a short integer, not a long text string of hexadecimal.  Is this a bug? or the new feature of Gecko/Marionette driver?

Here is where i ran into trouble:

1 - I start Firefox browser using Gecko/Marionette driver

```
final File file = new File("/Applications/geckodriver");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

It works fine.  Then I print out the value of the browser window session ID:

```
System.out.println("WindowHandle ID = " + driver.getWindowHandle());
```

It shows some short integers somewhere between 10 to 20 which are incorrect.

Then I print out the browser session and I am able to see the actual session ID (the MAC field between the () ):

```
Brwowser Session = BrowserSession [driver=FirefoxDriver: Firefox on MAC (**bc4eb9db-608b-5643-8ec9-136b6c54f6a2**), user=Admin, lastPage=null]
```

Now I think the new Gecko/Marionette messed up the `driver.getWindowHandle()` function ?  Because of this show-stopper, I am not able to switch the Selenium control from one window to another window or a pop-up.

**Question**:

Is there anyway that I can get the actual browser window session ID?  Please help.  I really need to get over this huge hurdle.  I've been searching for a solution but found none.

I'm writing in Java.

Thanks a lot folks.

Comment: Can you mention the Selenium version used?

Comment: @Chandra... Selenium v 3.0 beta; Firefox v 48.  It works for window only.  I tried to have the same setup for my Mac and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Selenium 2.53.1 + Firefox (v 48) with the following code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

or

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Chandra.. I did use the second setting.  Le me try the first one and see if it can get me over this hurdle.  Thanks

Comment: Chandra.. just try and it works great with the first option which is System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", file.getAbsolutePath());